# Spring boot and undertow - multipart threshold size doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, undertow

spring-boot version : 1.3.5
I set multipart.file-size-threshold=40MB in application properties.
When I am using embedded tomcat, I see that there is no write operations on disk during upload requests.
When I am using undertow, there are still write operations on disk.

How can i upload multiparts without disk writing via undertow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Undertow. Looking at its code it doesn't appear to honour the file size threshold and there's [a todo to that effect in `ManagedServlet`](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1.3.23.Final/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/core/ManagedServlet.java#L84).